# Nodejs - A for loop that makes a long series of asynchronous calls fails to exit

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, facebook-graph-api, asynchronous

I'm doing a series of 1.600.000 calls to a facebook API, and I need to check whether all the API calls have returned a response, and only in that case I have to call a function which basically saves some values on a database.

Here is my code:

```
var debugFile = fs.createWriteStream('debug.txt', {
   flags: 'a'
})

// ... Retrieving of all the idSenders and call of the function ...
asyncLoop(values)

const timer = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

async function asyncLoop(values) {  
  for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
    await timer(30);
    check(values[i].idSender, values[i].logged, values[i].site, values.length)
  }
}


function check(recipientId, logged, site, total) {

request({
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages",
    qs: {access_token: token},
    method: "POST",
    timeout: 1200000,
    json: {
        recipient: {id: recipientId},
        sender_action: "typing_off",
    }
},  function(error, response, body) {
        checked++;

        if (error) {
            errors++;
        } else {
            if(response.body.recipient_id) {
                if( logged == 0){
                    site.retrieved++;
                    debugFile.write(' +1');
                }
            } else {
                if( response.body.error && response.body.error.error_subcode == 1545041 ) {
                    if( logged == 1) {
                        site.optout++;
                        debugFile.write(' -1');
                    }
                } else if( response.body.error && response.body.error.code == 613) {
                    rate_limit++;
                    debugFile.write(' rate_limit');
                } else {
                    debugFile.write(' other_error');
                }
            }
        }

        if(checked == total) {
            saveAllResults()
        }

     }
  )
}
```

The problem is: when I launch the script for a restricted series of idSender (100000) it works perfectly, meaning it was able to do the final check ( checked == total ). 
But when I launch it for the complete set, after 6/7 hours all I have is the debug.txt file which reports a series of +1 or -1 (as I expect), not even one 'rate_limit' or 'other_error', and nothing saved on the database.
Due to the long execution time I'm not able to debug in a better way (at least nothing comes in my mind). 
Maybe what is happening here is that for some reason, with a large amount of idSender, it fails the check because some iteration has failed to increment checked variable.

************ UPDATE *************

Here is the saving part:

```
function saveAllResults() {
  let promises = [];
  promises.push( saveResult( site_1 ) );
  promises.push( saveResult( site_2 ) );

  Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    console.log('END')
    debugFile.write(" END");

    process.exit()
  }).catch(error=>{
    console.error(error)
  });
}

var saveResult = function(site) {
  return new Promise(function(reject, resolve) {
    mysql.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
      connection.query('INSERT INTO database (id_site, date, optout, retrieved, rate_limit) VALUES ('+site.id+', "'+yesterday+'", '+site.optout+', '+site.retrieved+', '+rate_limit+')', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error)
                reject(error);
            resolve(results);
       });
        connection.release();
    });
  })
}
```

Any suggestion would be great, thanks!

Comment: No error in the console?

Comment: Can we see `saveAllResults()`?

Comment: No error in the console. I also checked in the system logs for some clue but nothing as well

Comment: I do not see any error, or possible overload of variable possible ... We need to see `saveAllResults()` function. And `await timer(30); check();` -> `await check();` ?

Comment: I just added the saveAllResults() function

Comment: Thanks ! You have 1.6 million +1 and -1? In the `promises` (function saveAllResults) array, you have no` reject () `or` resolve () `error?

Comment: @Liberateur No: the sum of +1 and -1 is not near to 1.6 million. In fact I'm pretty sure the for loop "dies" before even calling saveAllResults (I don't see any message from this function)

Comment: Ok, you need to add `console.log('imhere1')`, `console.log('imhere2')`, `console.log('imhere3')`... Before all lines, we need to know where it stops precisely.

Comment: The only little clue that I have as far is that maybe the SSH broken pipe could cause the entire script to die. In fact I'm launching the script with the "node script.js" command, and I'm doing it through an SSH connection to the remote server.

Comment: Can you connect to the server in SSH and execute the same command? You will avoid to miss a log.